# To show other Apps while exiting

Tags: android, google-play

I wish to show my other apps under "More Apps" section of while exiting.

1. What is the the best way to do it ?
2. Is there is any common library to add my app icon and link of my app. so that It can be shown at the time of interest. It would be great if it is scrollable

Thanks is Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Well since these are your apps you can simply hard-code the icons into a RecyclerView or ListView along with a link leading to Google Play. This really doesn't require a third-party liubrary as it can easily be done by yourself.

If you really want to allow for future expansiveness, you could use a cloud platform like [parse](https://www.parse.com/) where you store the names of different apps as parse objects along with a link and an image (logo). Then you could write a custom adapter for your list which takes the parse objects from your cloud, and populates itself with the logo,link,title,etc.

> This is really a matter of comfort and preference rather than finding a library to do this for you. If you need help, feel free to ask, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can show a 'Dialog' asking if the user cares to check some of your other apps with two available options: 'yes' and 'no'. If the user chooses 
'no', close the dialog, if he chooses 'yes' - redirect him/her to the following url:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id={Your-Google-Account-Name}
```

This link will be opened either in the browser or in the Google Play app, whichever your user prefers, and it'll show him/her the list of all your apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding `finish()` ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())) method inside your Activity. If you're using multiple Activities, consider creating a base Activity so that you don't have to implement this in each Activity.

That said, please consider not doing this. As a user, I'd be super annoyed if I'm trying to close your app and you're not letting me do it. That'd be instant uninstallation from my side. Never annoy your users. Respect their experience.